# Create a column vector with zeros in the front in python

Tags: python, matlab

I just switched from MATLAB to python and I want help in translating a piece of MATLAB code to python.

I have a `1000 x 4` matrix in which the values in the `m'th column` represents a signal.

For simplicity I am changing the dimensions to `5 x 4`.

Let the values in the `m'th column` be `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

I want to `delay` this by `x` samples that is if `x=2` the delayed version will be `[0,0,1,2,3]`.

Its essentially adding `x zeros` to the front and removing `x values` from the back.

So the output is a `5x1 column vector`.

The MATLAB code is:

```
[zeros(2,1),signal(1:(end-2),m)];
```

The python code I wrote is:

```
[np.zeros((2,1)),signal[(length_of_signal-1)-2:,m]]
```

This doesn't seem to work and neither am I able to figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try with `vstack`:

```
np.random.seed(100)

x = 2
m = 3
a = np.random.randint(1, 5, (5,4))

>>> np.vstack((np.zeros((x, 1)), a[:,3][:len(a)-x][np.newaxis].T))

array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [4.],
       [3.],
       [2.]])
```

Note that you need the `np.newaxis` because the transpose of a 1D array is still a 1D array (unlike in MATLAB, where the default array is 2D).